# How to join series of queries in one query

Tags: sql-server-2008

> Hello,
>
> I have series of queries (Q1, Q2,Q3,Q4....) and my main query (Query1). 
>   I want to know how  to call Q2 and Q3.... and combine them in Query1.
>
> The query (Q2) is the first query that is used in main query.
>   Note: the Q6 is using UNION.

```
-- Main Query1  
SELECT T1.ic, T1.itn, T1.ap, T1.oh FROM Q2 INNER JOIN T1 ON Q2.ic = T1.ic  

-- Q2
SELECT DISTINCT Q4.ic FROM Q3 RIGHT JOIN Q4 ON Q3.ic = Q4.ic WHERE Q3.ic is NULL

-- Q3
SELECT DISTINCT T2.ic, T2.Q FROM T2 INNER JOIN Q4 ON T2.ic = Q4.ic WHERE T2.s > GETDATE()


The Query1 returns the following table of results:

T1.ic       T1.itn      T1.ap     T1.oh     
2           LED         8          e
2           SCREW       3          f 
1           WASHER      1          g
6           RES         0          z
...     ...
...     ...
```

> Can someone please explain?
>    Thank you for your help.

Comment: what do you mean by 'combine'? The queries return different numbers of columns, so you can't `UNION` them together. Do you want to `JOIN` them in some way?

Comment: Hi Ed,  The Q6 is using UNION. Yes I want to join them together. What I like to see is the main query call Q2 and Q2 call Q3 and so on

Comment: Oof, I'm hoping those aren't the actual names of the tables.  That looks pretty rough to work with.

Comment: have you tried subqueries? `select * from (select ...) a join (select ...) b on ...` etc? ie copy paste your queries into where they are used but add brackets around them and give them an alias and you're done.

Comment: Hi, Bohemian

>I try to run this query....

select [Multi-Level].ml from (Select [Multi-Level].Child FROM [PFTABLE] INNER JOIN [Multi-Level] on [PFTABLE].[PN] = [Multi-Level].[EI])
               a join 
              (select [PFTABLE].[PN] from  [PFTABLE] WHERE [PFTABLE].[Ct]='C') b

But I get this error message:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'b'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using CTEs that should work

```
WITH Q3 (ic, Q) 
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT T2.ic, T2.Q 
    FROM T2 
    INNER JOIN Q4 ON T2.ic = Q4.ic 
    WHERE T2.s > GETDATE()
),
Q2 (ic)
AS
(

    SELECT DISTINCT Q4.ic 
    FROM Q3 
    RIGHT JOIN Q4 ON Q3.ic = Q4.ic 
    WHERE Q3.ic is NULL
)
SELECT T1.ic, T1.itn, T1.ap, T1.oh 
FROM Q2 
INNER JOIN T1 ON Q2.ic = T1.ic
```

Comment: Your syntax is a bit off, you chain CTEs, not nest them, like `WITH A AS ( ... ), B AS ( ... ), C AS ( ... )`, etc., where `B` can refer to `A`, and `C` can refer to `A` and `B`, and so on. Obviously, use some more meaningful names than `A`, `B` and `C`, or when you come to maintain your code in six months time you'll regret it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH Q3 AS 
(
SELECT DISTINCT T2.ic, T2.Q FROM T2 INNER JOIN Q4 ON T2.ic = Q4.ic WHERE T2.s > GETDATE()
), 
Q2 AS 
(
SELECT DISTINCT Q4.ic FROM Q3 RIGHT JOIN Q4 ON Q3.ic = Q4.ic WHERE Q3.ic is NULL
)
SELECT T1.ic, T1.itn, T1.ap, T1.oh FROM Q2 INNER JOIN T1 ON Q2.ic = T1.ic
```

You could also use nested aliased subqueries, like this:

```
SELECT T1.ic, 
       T1.itn, 
       T1.ap, 
       T1.oh 
FROM   T1 
       JOIN (
             SELECT DISTINCT Q4.ic 
             FROM (
                   SELECT DISTINCT 
                          T2.ic, 
                          T2.Q 
                   FROM   T2 
                          INNER JOIN Q4 
                              ON T2.ic = Q4.ic 
                   WHERE  T2.s > GETDATE()
                  ) AS Q3 
                  RIGHT JOIN Q4 
                      ON Q3.ic = Q4.ic 
             WHERE Q3.ic is NULL
             ) AS Q2 
           ON Q2.ic = T1.ic
```